# XSFR-TOKEN and a laravel_session cookies not generating on server laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm doing a laravel 5.2 app but when I try to create an account it gives a csrf error..

When I check what cookies the website have, I find that I have no cookies, there should be a XSFR-TOKEN and a laravel_session cookies, but laravel is not generating any of those cookies, so it gives me a token not found when i try to create an account.. anyone know why it does that? any idea how to fix that?

Also just installed a new clean laravel and find out if I put the "app" view inside of a folder it also happends and doesnt generate the cookies, I have tried to change the folder permissions but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your route has the web middleware applied to it.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    //
});

<input type="hidden" name="_Token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also, you need to pass hidden filed with csrf token value in your form something like display above